# Nodemon is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, npm-install, nodemon

I've worked on a project at home and it worked just fine, but when i cloned a repo on a multiple lab pc's it always gives the same error.

nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
nodemon

```
 CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I believe my path is correct

I've tried installing nodemon globally with a lot of methods

```
npm install -g nodemon
npm insatll -g nodemon --save
```

I've also tried deleting node_modules folder and npm install again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing has really helped after trying around 25 different methods

**I had to fully uninstall node.js and reinstall it again.**

Answer (score 0):

switching to cmd from the terminal has helped.
`cmd`
default vscode terminal has some weird security rules that don't let nodemon work

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall nodemon locally by running: `npm uninstall nodemon`

Then install nodemon globally by running: `npm i -g nodemon`

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

for this type of error I think you need to set environment varibale
**C:\Users\2073668\AppData\Roaming\npm**
then run using nodemon command it will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

hello my friend I had faced the same problem and solved it by adding the running code for `nodemon` in the `package.json` file on script section by this way and run the

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "nodemon app.js"
},
```

and then run `npm run serve` in the terminal panel

I am sure that will gonna help you and good luck

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Make sure your package.json has the devDependencies and scripts associated with nodemon listed below.

```
{
  "name": "foldername",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index",
    "dev": "nodemon index"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Then to start it type this in the console:

```
npm run dev
```

This should launch your dev script which will allow nodemon.