# Nodemon not recognized although I can find it in the npm list

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, nodemon

I installed nodemon globally in Powershell:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

This is the result:

```
changed 32 packages, and audited 33 packages in 6s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Now I want to open the help function of Nodemon:

```
nodemon --help options
```

But I get this error message:

```
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1  
+ nodemon --help options
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I try to understand why the term nodemon is not recognized and how can fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodemon is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70218209/nodemon-is-not-recognized-as-a-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the nodemon in the command prompt/ Terminal? I would recommend to use command prompt or bash terminal while using the nodemon.

If you are using the PowerShell you need some config I guess.

As I faced the issue previously in PowerShell, but worked fine with terminal. Not sure about it. But, try using the command prompt / terminal